# Communication between two docker containers based on multi-tenant architecture

Tags: django, docker, multi-tenant, docker-network

I have two django projects (mircroservices), running in separate docker containers. Both projects are using [django-tenant-schemas](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). How can I send a request from *serice-bar* to *service-foo* on url `http://boohoo.site.com:18150/api/me/`, `18150` is the PORT of *project-a*? I need to use the tenant url so that *project-a* can verify the tenant and process the request.

I can send a request by using the container name, but that doesn't work because if I use `http://site.foo:18150/api/me`, it sends the request successfully, but there's no tenant with definition `site.foo`.

Here's the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: site.postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  foo:
    container_name: site.foo
    build:
      context: ../poll
    command: python /app/foo/src/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:18150
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=site.postgres
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=main.settings.dev
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "18150:18150"

  bar:
    container_name: site.bar
    build:
      context: ../toll
    command: python /app/bar/src/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:18381
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=site.postgres
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=main.settings.dev
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "18381:18381"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using aliases on the default (or any other...) network. For more info on this feature, see the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks). I checked and this is supported by your current compose file version (3.3) although I do suggest you move up to the latest supported one if possible (3.7).

For compactness, I'm only reproducing the modified `foo` service declaration below where I only added the necessary `networks` stanza.

```
  foo:
    container_name: site.foo
    build:
      context: ../poll
    command: python /app/foo/src/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:18150
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=site.postgres
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=main.settings.dev
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - boohoo.site.com
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "18150:18150"
```

After this change, your `foo` service container will be reachable from any other container on the same network either with `foo` (the service name), `site.foo` (your custom container name) or `boohoo.site.com` (the network alias).

Comment: Thank you so much. just one question, can I have aliases as regex, like `*.site.com`?

Comment: Well you can... but that will create an alias literrally named `*.site.com`, not a wildcard as you are looking for. This is not supported.